# individually target multiple instances of the same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tabular .tab').prependTo($('.tabular'));
    });
</script>
```

which I am using on this html

```
<div class="tabular"> <a class="tab">Example 1</a>

    <div class="tab_content">Ridiculus condimentum. Integer lacinia imperdiet felis morbi egestas dapibus
        leo.</div> <a class="tab">Example 2</a>

    <div class="tab_content">Auctor fames pede sem. Ullamcorper rhoncus pharetra purus pellentesque
        nisi.</div> <a class="tab">Example 3</a>

    <div class="tab_content">Lobortis hendrerit tellus maecenas pellentesque purus ante iaculis feugiat
        nullam.</div>
</div>
```

but it only works if I have only 1 tabbed section on a page, If I want 3 tabbed sections on a page I have to re-write it to this...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tabular-1 .tab-1').prependTo($('.tabular-1'));
        $('.tabular-2 .tab-2').prependTo($('.tabular-2'));
        $('.tabular-3 .tab-3').prependTo($('.tabular-3'));
    });
</script>
```

as well as re-writing the html and css.
Is there anyway of re-writing the first script so that I don't have to add a new line of code every time I add a tabbed section?
from looking at jquery I think it involves adding indexes and/or using $(this) but i'm getting know where slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the collection `$('.tabular .tab')` doesn't group them according to their parent element, so `.prependTo('.tabular')` will move all tabs before the last `.tabular` on your page (document order is honoured).

My best advice would be to use `.each()` to iterate each parent and move their inner tabs:

```
$('.tabular').each(function() {
    $('.tab', this).prependTo(this);
});
```

This makes the tabs "stick" with their parent.